# I am trying to fill a form from console

Tags: javascript, browser, console

Basicly I am trying to fill some boxes in a form and then press send to fill a form quickly.
I thought the best way was to go to console in the browser and type a command like this;

```
//fill the value
document.getElementsByClassName("form-control").item("1").value=11111;
document.getElementsByClassName("form-control").item("2").value=22222;

//press the button
document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-success mr-2").item("0").click();
```

But for some reason although I can see that the value changes the from doesn't think it has been edited. When I try to submit it, it submits as empty.

Comment: If you have get class by `getElementsByClassName`, you should select one of arrays in the class to set value.

Comment: from document.getElementsByClassName("form-control") to document.getElementsByClassName("form-control")[number]

Comment: @jacobkim .item will do the same as accessing it like an array

Comment: It's not very likely, that we can help you solve the problem without seeing the form's code.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use form while submit form instead of button click.
Works on your example.

```
//Fill the values
document.getElementsByClassName("form-control").item("0").value=11111;
document.getElementsByClassName("form-control").item("1").value=22222;
//Submit form
document.querySelector("form").submit();
```

Answer (score -1):

For me works using JS path, you can inspect the element and select copy, then js path and use it between "" in the next line:

document.querySelector("").click() -- if you want to click on an element or;

document.querySelector("").value=""; -- if you want to add a value to an element, inside the second "" of value you can insert your variable or string

Obviusly these commands use it inside browser console

Comment: `querySelector` has nothing to do with xpath

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).